# Using optional arguments in an Excel Sub

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am writing a VBA program in Excel 2016.  I want to create a method with an optional argument.  The following little sample illustrates the problem:

```
Private Sub TestMethod(RowNumber As Long, Optional KeyNumber As Long = -1)
    If KeyNumber >= 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Received key number " & KeyNumber)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Key number not received")
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
    TestMethod (1, 2)  '  Error on this line
End Sub
```

When I typed the ")" on the error line, Excel pops up this error:

"Compile Error:  Expected: ="

From what I've seen on the internet, my syntax should be correct.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Subs dont need `()` on the parameters if you take them out it works for me

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures

Comment: The parentheses are forcing the expression `(x, y)` to be evaluated as a value, and _that_ value is the argument that the procedure receives. This is true regardless of whether you're calling a `Sub`, a `Function`, or a `Property`; what matters is whether or not a return value is captured. When the return value is discarded, discard the parentheses. When you need to capture a return value,  that's when you need the parentheses. `MsgBox ("Message", "Title")` doesn't compile either ;-)

Comment: Note the space between the name and the opening parenthesis `MsgBox (` - when the return value is captured, there's never a space there, it's always `Result = MsgBox(`; the space is the VBIDE signalling that it is parsing whatever follows as an expression, as opposed to an argument list: that's why trying to pass two or more arguments within parentheses is a syntax error: the expression can't be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

My code has two versions. In the first case, I put the arguments in parentheses, and use `Call` to call the subroutine:

```
Private Sub TestMethod(RowNumber As Long, Optional KeyNumber As Long = -1)
    If KeyNumber >= 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Received key number " & KeyNumber)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Key number not received")
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
    Call TestMethod (1, 2)  '  Error on this line
End Sub
```

The alternative is to call `TestMethod` without parentheses:

```
Private Sub TestMethod(RowNumber As Long, Optional KeyNumber As Long = -1)
    If KeyNumber >= 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Received key number " & KeyNumber)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Key number not received")
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
    TestMethod 1, 2  '  Error on this line
End Sub
```